# scraping "next pages" using PHP, cURL, simplehtmldom

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I finally got my scraper working (somewhat), but now I'd like to know how I can automatically go to the next page and scrape the same info from there. I'm using cURL to copy the entire page (otherwise I get a 500 error). Here's my code:

```
<?

// create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/results.asp?&j=t&page_no=1");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $html = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);      
// print $html . "\n";

require 'simple_html_dom.php';           
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load($html);
foreach($dom->find("div[@id='schoolsearch'] tr") as $data){
    $tds = $data->find("td");
    if(count($tds)==3){
        $record = array(
            'school' => $tds[1]->plaintext, 
            'city' => $tds[2]->plaintext
        );
        print json_encode($record) . "\n";
        file_put_contents('schools.csv', json_encode($record) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

?>
```

It's not perfect, but it's what works right now! Anyone know how I can move to the next pages?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a loop:

```
$maxPages = 10;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxPages; $i++) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/results.asp?&j=t&page_no=$i");

    etc...

}
```

You'll need to tidy up a bit more,to avoiding including that file on every page, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the help! unfortunately it's still not working for me. I wrapped everything in a loop (that's what I was supposed to do right? sorry, I'm still new at this) and I'm receiving the same dataset (only the first page).

Comment: The assumption in the code is that http://example.com/results.asp?&j=t&page_no=2 will actually return the second page of results. You did change the CURLOPT_URL line to include the loop counter didn't you?

Comment: yep, I did. any other ideas?

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code, and see what is not working as expected. Repost your up-to-date code.